# How can I add a "Shop Now" for a products with variations and simple products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I had the nex code, but it works only for a simple products and it doesn't consider quantity or variations of the product.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'by_now' );

function by_now() {

$current_product_id = get_the_ID();

// get the product based on the ID
$product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

// get the "Checkout Page" URL
$checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

// run only on simple products
if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
   echo '<div class="test"><a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'"
   type="submit"class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Pagar ahora</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: what do you mean to add shop now do you want only text to be added before the cart button?  or you want to change the add to cart button text?  from this code above you are  adding another add to cart button

Comment: @kashalo yep, i want to a new button just before to "Add to cart" button, I want the new button could to shop the product directly when the user click it.